# LoaderService issue using MSAL Service for login in Angular

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, angular-http-interceptors, msal-angular, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I'm developing an Angular app that requires MS credentials for get logged in. Furthermore I'm using an Http Interceptor for showing up a loader component when any HttpClient's call is in use.
My problem here is when I log into my app, the calls that makes the MSALService library don't show the loader and my app seems to be freezed until the MSAL configuration calls are done.

My Interceptor:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {finalize} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {LoaderService} from './loader.service';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHeaders,HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpClient,HttpParams,HttpResponse,HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  service_count = 0; // initialize the counter.

  constructor(public loaderService: LoaderService) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.service_count++;

    this.loaderService.is_loading.next(true);
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      finalize(
        () => {
          this.service_count--;
          if (this.service_count === 0) {
            this.loaderService.is_loading.next(false);
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

My Loader Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderService {
  public is_loading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor() { }
}
```

[The calls that I can't intercept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwnsc.png)

Thank you so much

Comment: please show us what your LoaderService is doing.

Comment: @devmiles.com My LoaderService: 
`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderService {
  public is_loading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor() { }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a complete answer with the snippets you provided.
You should have included:

1. the snippet where you're using the loader
2. the snippet of the module you're providing your interceptor

I can only give you feedback on some quick observations.

Your interceptor should be decorated with `@Injectable()` without the `{ provided: root }`, and in the `app.module.ts` you should provide your interceptor like this:

```
providers: [
   { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: InterceptorService, multi: true }
]
```

You may find [this article about interceptors](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-interceptors-a-complete-guide-7294e2317ecf) helpful.

On another note, I think the way you are using the `service_count` to determine when to stop the loader is just asking for trouble.